# Nielsen Nitro range (Blueberry range) refresh

Tags: vba

I am looking for VBA to refresh Nielsen Nitro range.

Nielsen Nitro is an application to extract data from the Database. Also range is called Blueberry range to refresh the data

I've tried to use below VBA, but it was not working

```
Dim acnNitro As New ACNNITRO
Dim acnNitroUpdate As ACNielsenNitro.ACNNitroUpdate
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim bret as Boolean
acnNitro.ParentApp = Application
acnNitroUpdate = acnNitro.ACNNitroUpdate
WS = ActiveSheet 'or Set WS = WorkSheets("My Sheet")
bret = acnNitroUpdate.UpdateAllNRanges(WS, ntrSelectGet)
acnNitro = Nothing
acnNitroUpdate = Nothing
WB = Nothing
```

#### screenshot

[image: screenshot]

I have also provided screenshot for the range.

Can you please suggest me for VBA code?

Answer (score 2):

I have written a similar code for a project, find code below. It might help you!

```html
Public Sub NeilsenRefresh()

Dim str_RngDesc As Variant
Dim bRet As Boolean

Dim RngObj As NITRORange
Dim acnNITROUpdt As Object
Dim acnNITRO As Object
Dim NRangeObj As NITRORange
Dim cRange As Object
Dim Bubble As String
Set acnNITRO = CreateObject("ACNielsenNitro.ACNNitro")
Set acnNITRO.ParentApp = ActiveWorkbook.Application
Set acnNITROUpdt = acnNITRO.ACNNitroUpdate
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro")

WkbName = .Range("G9").Value
Path = .Range("G12").Value
Bubble = .Range("G15").Value
Atribute = .Range("G18").Value
WkList = .Range("G6").Value

End With

'Sheets("Data").Activate

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

  lr = .Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

  If lr > 1 Then
  
  .Range("Q1:Q" & lr).ClearContents
  .Range("A2:A" & lr).ClearContents
  .Range("B3:C" & lr).ClearContents
  .Range("D2:D" & lr).ClearContents
  .Range("R2:R" & lr).ClearContents
  .Range("S2:S" & lr).ClearContents
  
 End If
  
 Set WkbList = Workbooks.Open(Path & "\" & WkList & ".xlsx")
Set wks = WkbList.Sheets("Sheet1")
lrw = wks.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
wks.Range("A2:A" & lrw).Copy
.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
wks.Range("B2:B" & lrw).Copy
.Range("D2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
  
 lr = .Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

 .Range("B2:C" & lr).FillDown
.Calculate
  
 Set wksmiss = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Missing Records")

 lrw = wksmiss.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
If lrw > 1 Then wksmiss.Range("A2:B" & lrw).ClearContents

 
 .Range("A1:D" & lr).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="#N/A"

 lrw = .Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

 If lrw > 1 Then

   .Range("B2:B" & lrw).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    wksmiss.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
   .Range("D2:D" & lrw).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    wksmiss.Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
   .Range("A2:D" & lrw).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete Shift:=xlUp
   
 End If

 .Range("A1:D" & lr).AutoFilter
.Range("B2:C" & lr).FillDown
.Calculate

  
 .Calculate
.Range("A2:A" & lr).Copy
.Range("Q1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
.Range("Q1:Q" & lr).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

  lrd = .Range("Q1048576").End(xlUp).Row
.Range("R1:R" & lrd).FillDown
.Range("S1:S" & lrd).FillDown
.Range("A1").Value = "Cum Name"
.Calculate

  For i = 1 To lrd
  
   CumName = .Range("Q" & i).Value
   Cnt = .Range("R" & i).Value
   FstIndex = .Range("S" & i).Value
  
   RowNo = FstIndex + Cnt - 1
   val1 = .Range("C" & RowNo).Value
  
   If CumConcat = "" Then
    
     CumConcat = val1 & ","
     
   Else
   
     val1 = Replace(val1, "MKT", "")
     CumConcat = CumConcat & val1 & ","
     
   End If
  
  
  Next


End With


Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(Path & "\" & WkbName & ".xlsx")

Set RngObj = acnNITRO.ACNRangeUtility.GetNRange(Bubble, ActiveWorkbook)
RngObj.DimCount = 4
RngObj.DimIndex = Atribute
RngObj.DimGetString = CumConcat

str_RngDesc = RngObj.RangeDescription
Set acnNITROUpdt = acnNITRO.ACNNitroUpdate

bRet = acnNITROUpdt.UpdateNRange(ActiveWorkbook, Bubble, 0)

WkbList.Close
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Activate
MsgBox "Nielsen Refresh Completed", vbInformation

End Sub
```